# How to stop capacitive buttons being triggered by acrylic sheet

Tags: arduino, touch-panel

So I have a bunch of capacitive buttons sitting behind a large 50x50cm acrylic sheet and whenever I place there acrylic sheet over the buttons, they start triggering all by themselves. I can't figure out how to stop this. Any ideas?

Comment: What's sensing the capacitive buttons? Is there a way to decrease the sensitivity?

Comment: Yes. Just one. The dielectric constant of acrylic is about 2-3 depending on exactly what it is and how its made. Just as a guess, I'd assume there could be problems here. You might consider trying _different_ capactive buttons by different manufacturers to see if the problem can be resolved. Or else use a material other than acrylic that has a constant closer to 1 and the other features you're looking for.

Comment: Is it only a problem immediately after placing the acrylic sheet over the buttons? There are anti-static spray-on coatings which as a bonus would add some scratch-resistance; I haven't tried any.

Comment: I probably should add that if you _designed_ a capacitive system to _incorporate_ the dielectric constant of acrylic (or glass, for that matter), then things might work well. I've never attempted such a design though. Hopefully, someone who has may be able to provide some specific guidance.

Comment: @jonk The whole project is using arduino. The capacitive buttons are simply small copper squares with a 1 mega ohm resistor (something like that anyway - I forget how much it actually is) and then I have them all connected up to the arduino. I have though of an mdf back however I don't really like the aesthetics of it. I've considered putting something in between the buttons and the acrylic like a small block of mdf, but I'd then have to lower the threshold necessary to register a touch, and then I would assume the acrylic would come back in range, and trigger the buttons again...Any thoughts?

Comment: No, not really. I wish I had specific experiences to share. But on this, I don't. I have used the MSP430's capacitive switch module and it works very well. But I didn't design it, just used it. And I don't know what it would do if I put acrylic in front of it. I could try and see, I suppose. I know theory, broadly speaking, but not the practice. And I think you need more of that. If something crosses my mind, I'll toss a note.

Answer (score 1):

The acrylic sheet can present a large DC offset, caused by the stored static charge on its surface. I suspect that charge is being detected by your port,  masking the touch signal itself.

To ignore that charge, you need to filter out DC and only pass AC.

I would suggest this approach...

Excite one side of the switch (the transmitter half) with a high frequency square wave, and the other side (the receiver half)
should connected to a high pass filter, to attenuate any lower frequencies / DC, so that only the high frequency component is passed to the port.

So, between the sensing element and the arduino, have a couple of stages of suitably tailored high pass RC filters, perhaps feeding a CMOS inverter to act as a buffer, then feed that filtered signal to your port.